# File.Delete(x) works where File.Copy(y, x, true) would fail

Tags: c#, windows, copy, .net-3.5

I was trying to copy an existing file to another local path, where a file with the same file might already exist. So this is was my first option:

```
File.Copy(outputFileFullName, newFileName, true);
```

On some occasions, if `newFileName` already exists, this fails with `UnauthorizedAccessException` trying to access the existing file.
Ok then, what I get is that for some reason the program has no permission to delete the existing file.

But, much to my surprise, on the same files this code works and no exception is thrown:

```
if (File.Exists(newFileName))
      File.Delete(newFileName);
    
File.Copy(outputFileFullName, newFileName, true);
```

What is `File.Delete(x)` doing differently than `File.Copy(y, x, true)` in terms of deleting the existing file?

Comment: Maybe the destination file is `read only` therefore can be removed, but not overwritten

Comment: @TomasChabada As per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.delete?view=net-5.0),  `File.Delete()` should also throw an exception if the file is read-only.

Comment: @TomasChabada files are not read-only.

Comment: Maybe this case is it: _"overwrite is true, **destFileName exists and is hidden, but sourceFileName is not hidden**."_ ? (Emphasis by me)

Comment: @Fildor Both source and destination files are not hidden.

Comment: Too bad. That would have been my last guess before resorting to "earth radiation" or "aliens".